# Parsing JSON using com.google.Gson

Tags: json, gson

I am very new to JSON parsing. I need help in this case. I am using Gson parsing.

```
class ElemntList
    {
      @SerializedName("elem")
      private List elem;
    }

class Element
{
    @SerializedName("key")
    private String key;
}
```

JSON string:

```
json =  {"elem":[{"key":"4BC8909A902F4B29"},{"key":"4BC8909A902F4B29"}]}
```

I am using ElemntList

`proddetl = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), ElemntList.class);`

How can I parse Element objects from proddet1 object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "{\"elem\":[{\"key\":\"4BC8909A902F4B29\"},{\"key\":\"4BC8909A902F4B29\"}]}";
        ElemntList info = gson.fromJson(s, ElemntList.class);
        System.out.println(info);

        for(Elem e : info.getElem()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey());
        }
   }
```